# Need to create an module to display datas of component in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I am an newbie to Joomla. 
I have created an new component with help of this `http://joomlacomponentcreator.codelydia.com/` website.

Now i need to get the values from component and display it in fronted with help of module. Similar to **banner module**.

Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a model for your component, which gets data from the database, you should create an Instance of that model in your module like this:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.model' );
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath( JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_mycompo/models', 'YourModel' );
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'Items', 'YourModel' );
```

Then you use a model method to get the data you want:

```
$data = $model->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the component using http://www.component-creator.com you will get many more features such as full ACL support, SQL import, front end editing and many more types of fields including foreign key fields. And as a bonus you can also build a module that can display your data.